# Rendering autolinks with Markdown package

Tags: markdown, url, rendering

I'd like Markdown package to render markdown autolinks `<some-url>` as LaTeX `\url{some-url}`, so I added a custom naive link renderer. Here is a MWE showing all the cases:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[smartEllipses,inlineFootnotes,hybrid]{markdown}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}

#### Standard URL/link management

1. https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf
2. <https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf>
3. [link-label](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)
4. [](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)
5. \url{https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf}

I'd like case 2 to behave like case 5.

\end{markdown}

\markdownSetup{ renderers = {link = {\url{#2}}} } % this should stay in preamble

\begin{markdown}

#### Custom URL/link management

Previous cases 2 and 4 behave (as wanted) like case 5, but case 3 behavior is lost:

1. https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf
2. <https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf>
3. [link-label](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)
4. [](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)
5. \url{https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf}

\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

which delivers

[image]

Unfortunately with such custom renderer I lose the standard rendering of markdown `[some-label](some-url)`.

Is it possible to define a custom link renderer able to change behavior only of case 2?

N.B. I use XeLaTeX for compilation.

##### Follow up

Hint at https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/issues/79#issuecomment-852223526 let you avoid some special character issue you might have depending on the content of your URLs.

Comment: Have you read 2.3.1.7 of the user manual (https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.html)?

Comment: @PhineasGreene No, but I read the PDF on CTAN which is similar. This other example however let me understand that using `\url{}` inside redefinition of link renderer is too much, since `\texttt{}` is enough (and better for special character handling). Unfortunately the problem with `\texttt{}` is that it misses automatic hyphenation at every character which `\url{}` does automatically.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't need to alter the catcodes of `&` and `_` globally, since this will impede your ability to use subscripts in math (`_`) and write table separators (`&`) in the `hybrid` mode. You should be able to use `\detokenize{...}` inside the renderer to convert all tokens except spaces into category 12 (other) when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.html#link-renderer) defines the link renderer as follows:

> #### [2.3.1.7 Link Renderer](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.html#link-renderer)
>
> The `\markdownRendererLink` macro represents a hyperlink. It receives four arguments: the label, the fully escaped URI that can be directly typeset, the raw URI that can be used outside typesetting, and the title of the link.

From this definition, it is not clear how you would differentiate between labeled links (`[label](https://foo.bar/ "title")`) and autolinks (`<https://foo.bar/>`, `<john@doe.edu>`). However, the Lua parser actually makes it easy to distinguish between these:

- For autolink URIs, the label (`#1`) and the fully-escaped URI (`#2`) are equivalent.
- For autolink e-mails, the label with the `mailto:` prefix (`mailto:#1`) and the fully-escaped URI (`#2`) are equivalent.

[image: An excerpt from the technical documentation]

Equipped with this knowledge, you can define a different rendering for labeled links, autolink e-mails and autolink URIs:

```tex
\markdownSetup{
    renderers = {
        link = {%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}{%
                % Handle autolink URI. <https://foo.bar/>
            }{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{mailto:#1}{#2}}{%
                    % Handle autolink e-mail. <john@doe.edu>
                }{%
                    % Handle labeled link. [label](https://foo.bar/ "title")
                }%
            }%
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** [Since Markdown 2.14.0](https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/issues/91), the `relativeReferences` option allows you to type [relative references](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.2) and have them be treated as links:

```
I conclude in Section <#conclusion>.

Conclusion {#conclusion .some-snippet}
==========
In this paper, we have discovered that most grandmas would rather eat
dinner with their grandchildren than get eaten. Begone, wolf!
```

You can detect this specific case by testing whether the first character
of the URL is `#`, although other relative references (`?key=value` or `./some/file.tex`) are possible.

```tex
\usepackage{expl#}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\markdownRendererLinkPrototype{
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\#=12  % Make hash sign (#) into an other character.
    \def\next##1##2##3##4{
        \endgroup
        \tl_set:Nx
            \l_tmpa_tl
            { \str_range:nnn { ##3 } { 1 } { 1 } }
        \str_if_eq:NNTF
            \l_tmpa_tl
            \c_hash_str
            {
                % Handle identifier \str_range:nnn { ##3 } { 2 } { -1 }
                % following a hash sign.
            }{
                % Handle others types of links.
            }
    }
    \next
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me to use:

`\def\markdownRendererLink#1#2#3#4{\href{#3}{#1}{}{}}`

For example the markdown `[StackExchange](stackexchange.com)` generates the latex `\href{stackexchange.com}{StackExchange}`